# Design for logging or adding logging afterwards?

Tags: .net, logging

When writing a new application or infrastructure, do you consider logging right from the start? And thus have a lot of classes importing/using an ILogger interface (inside constructor for injection) for example?

What if you already have (most of) your application in place, but didn't think of logging in most or all of your classes. How would you end up adding logging to them?

My concern with adding afterwards is that if you need logging deep down into your dependency chain, you might end up having to add an ILogger interface to many classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always consider logging from the start.

Firstly there is the decision of which logging framework to use, but that is generally a quick choice. I personally often use log4net, which means each class uses the static LogManager.GetLogger to get an instance of a logger. The actual behaviours of each log call is then defined in config (where should I log too, what level should I log at, etc).

However, more importantly, you should be thinking of *what needs logging* as you are actually developing your application. There is no point at which you are more tuned into your code than when you are writing it, and you probably have a better idea of what needs logging then than at any other time. It is far easier to retrospectively remove overly verbose logging that you don't need that add logging that should be there.

So yes - always think about logging as you start your application, don't try and retro-fit it if you can help it.

**[EDIT: In response to your question about how to inject]**

Possibly the simplest approach (assuming you are not using an IoC container) is to go down the route of property or constructor injection. Personally, I much prefer the latter for this sort of thing, so I would end up with something like this for log4net:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly ILog _logger;

    // usually I don't supply a logger directly, 
    // hence I let this ctor get a logger from the log manager.
    public MyClass() : this (LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass)))
    {

    }

    // this ctor only gets called directly if I want to mock out logging
    public MyClass(ILog logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't a static bad for testing? How would you mock it? or would you just have a special configuration for when testing?

Comment: @Rodi - you're absolutely right - in fact what I said above is a simplification of what I really do, for brevity's sake. The logger itself in log4net is of type ILog, and so this can be mocked and injected in using an IoC, or accessed via a "lazy-load" property that only calls the LogManager.GetLogger if a mock logger has not already been supplied.

Comment: Have you got an example or a link to one somewhere? Thanks.

Comment: I am planning on using an IoC container, so I guess then you will depend on that and leave out the parameterless constructor? (Your edit was quite obvious, don't know what else I was expecting ;)

Comment: Depending on your IoC, you may either leave out the parameterless constructor (if it is a "parameter injection IoC"), or may leave out the overloaded constructor and have a public logger property (for property injection), or have a public "initialize" method for method injection.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you have "many" classes implement `ILogger`? It should be enough to have one or two classes implement it, e.g. "DatabaseLogger" and "FileLogger". An instance of the ILogger implementation needs to be passed around, that's right, This can be done by a singleton or by dependency injection.

Comment: I suspect he doesn't mean implement, I suspect he means import or inject; so many classes are having an ILogger injected. I could be wrong.

Comment: When using log4net it is common to instantiate a private static ILog instance in each class that uses logging.  In this way the hierarchical logger names reflect the structure of the namespaces and class names used in the project.

Comment: Indeed I don't meant "implement", but rather "use", "import" or "inject". I edited my question.

Comment: With dependency injection you end up changing a lot of classes to let them accept an ILogger interface, right? So it will have quite an impact doing that afterwards (in an existing app). Using a singleton seems better, but I hear bad things about singletons, especially in a testing environment.

Comment: As Rob points out, introducing the logger afterwards is always a pain. You either have to change the classes to accept the interface (it doesn't need to be in the constructor, it can be a property as well), or you introduce a tight coupling to a singleton which makes unit testing harder, as you correctly mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use a singleton class for logging. This class can be configured to write to a log file, a database table or the Windows event log.

Comment: Isn't a singleton bad for testing? How would you mock it? or would you just have a special configuration for testing?

Comment: I guess this depends on your application and architecture. I normally try to write small and not very complex methods. Then I would have a lot of unit tests, and do the logging within the unit testing framework. But I guess you can use a singleton class while doing unit tests as well in many cases.